# how to read string in memo delphi

Tags: swiftmailer

how to read a string

```
Fandy L Guaje
LONDON
```

of fragment following message, which is separated with: 50K :/ and: 53A :/

```
enter code here
: 50K 551 110 032 657 :/
Fandy L Guaje
LONDON
: 53A 969 753 000 990 :/
```

and insert it into a table